# missing-FROM clause Error in LibreOffice Base Listbox

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice-base

I'm using LibreOffice Base 5.3.4.2 as a front-end for a postgres database. In postgres, I have the following tables:

`lu_ss_unit_types` (lookup table that stores different unit types)

`ss_unit_mix` (uses `fkey` from `lu_ss_unit_types`)

`ss_rent_surveys` (uses `fkey` from `ss_unit_mix`)

In LO, I have a subform for `ss_rent_surveys` under a form for `ss_unit_mix`. Within the `ss_rent_surveys` subform table control there is a listbox column for `ss_unit_mix_id` which I've labeled "Unit Type" and concatenates information from the `ss_unit_mix` and `ss_unit_types` tables.

Here's the problem: the following code in the List Content for the listbox control I get the error "missing-FROM clause entry for table 'm'." However, when I run the SQL straight from PGAdmin, it works fine. What gives?

```
SELECT t.unit_type||' ('||
CASE WHEN m.interior IS TRUE THEN 'Int' Else 'Ext' END||'/'||
CASE WHEN m.upper_level IS TRUE THEN 'Upper' Else '1st' END||'/'||
CASE WHEN m.climate_controlled IS TRUE THEN 'CC' Else 'Standard' END||')', 
m.ss_unit_mix_id 
FROM properties.ss_unit_mix m
LEFT JOIN lookup.lu_ss_unit_types t ON t.ss_unit_type_id = m.ss_unit_type_id;
```

Comment: It seemed to work OK when I tried running it from the Queries section in LO Base.  Is the `properties` schema owned by the same user that the LO Base file uses to connect?  Perhaps it's a permissions problem, or LO Base is starting from a different schema.  Try simplifying the query to see if it works.

Comment: @Jim I solved the problem. Apparently I needed to add a space between `m` and `LEFT JOIN` in the List Content box of the listbox control. How do I mark this question as solved?

As an aside, I was also having a problem that the SQL in the List Content field was being partially deleted when the form was re-opened after saving. The fix was to create a saved query in LO Base and then point the listbox to the query rather than trying to type the SQL directly into the List Content field.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.  To close the question, add your own answer and then accept it.  You may need to wait a few days first.  https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/